# Marking secondary targets and checking for edits

Tags: makefile

I'm using Make to extract and generate figures for a scientific report. It being declarative is very nice for writing down where data is and how to convert it into a figure. My makefile looks somewhat like this (with `plots` being the main target):

```
plots: some_specific_figure.png some_other_figure.png yet_another_figure.png

%.png: %.fig.py
    $(GENFIG) $<

%.fig.py: %.raw.fig.py
    cp $< $@

some_specific_figure.raw.fig.py:
    $(GETDATA) some/super/specific/simulation/results/directory/ $@

some_other_figure.raw.fig.py:
    $(GETDATA) some/different/arbitrary/simulation/directory/ $@

yet_another_figure.raw.fig.py:
    # etcetera
```

Now, in the end, I want to **manually edit** these `*.fig.py` files ( `some_specific_figure.fig.py`, `some_other_figure.fig.py`, etc), because the raw extracted data doesn't contain the right plot/axis/line title, axis range, etc.

What I would like Make to do, is

- Extract `%.fig.raw.py` from the data directory if it doesn't exist. Copy it to `%.fig.py` to allow editing later.
- Keep the `%.fig.py` file after building.
- Just build `%.png` from an existing `%.fig.py` without overwriting it with the `%.raw.fig.py` file. If `%.fig.py` exists or has been edited, Make should just use that.

What is an easy/concise way to do this? Marking `.SECONDARY: %.fig.py` didn't do the trick, when I do that, Make still deletes `%.fig.py` at the end!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EXTENDED**

If I understood your problem well, you need to make %.fig.py if it does not exist and leave as it is, if it does exists.

At first if you do not want to delete the intermediate files, you should define them as precious:

```
.PRECIOUS: %.fig.py %.fig.raw.py
```

On the other hand if `%.fig.py` dependent on `%.raw.fig.py` it will be rebuild if the later is edited. So make `%.fig.py` not dependent and create `%.raw.fig.py` only when `%.fig.py` is processed.

An example Makefile:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

.PHONY: plots clean

plots: a.png

%.png: %.fig.py
        echo +$@+ $<
        touch $@

%.fig.py: 
        echo Construct $(@:.fig.py=.fig.raw.py)
        touch $(@:.fig.py=.fig.raw.py)
        echo +$@+
        touch $@

.PRECIOUS: %.fig.py

clean:
        echo [Clean]
        rm -f *.png *.fig.py *.fig.raw.py
```

Output if a.png does not exists:

```
$ ./a.mak 
echo Construct a.fig.raw.py
Construct a.fig.raw.py
touch a.fig.raw.py
echo +a.fig.py+
+a.fig.py+
touch a.fig.py
echo +a.png+ a.fig.py
+a.png+ a.fig.py
touch a.png
```

So it creates `a.fig.raw.py`, then `a.fig.py` and finally a.png`. Intermediate files are not deleted.

Output if `a.fig.raw.py` is edited (I used `touch a.fig.raw.py`):

```
$ touch a.fig.raw.py
$ ./a.mak 
make: Nothing to be done for `plots'.
```

Output if `a.fig.py` is edited:

```
$ touch a.fig.py; ./a.mak
echo +a.png+ a.fig.py
+a.png+ a.fig.py
touch a.png
```

In this case `a.png` is remade, but `a.fig.raw.py` is not touched at all.

**ADDED**

Other interesting question how can a makefile done to be dependent on a directory. E.g. some file is created into directories `foo1/bar1` and `foo2/bar2`. If a new file is written one of this dirs the file `foo<n>_bar<n>.png` should be created.

Here is the makefile:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

.PHONY: clean plots

DIRS := foo1/bar1 foo2/bar2
TARGETS := $(addsuffix .png,$(subst /,_,$(DIRS)))

plots: $(TARGETS)

# Avoid to try to remake the makefile itself
a.mak: ;
# Avoid to try to remake the dirs
$(DIRS): ;

%.png: %.fig.py
        touch "$@"

%.fig.py: %.raw.fig.py
        if [ -s "$@" ]; then touch "$@"; else cp "$<" "$@"; fi

.PRECIOUS: %.fig.py %.raw.fig.py

clean:
        echo [Clean]
        rm -f *.png *.fig.py *.fig.raw.py

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.raw.fig.py: $$(subst _,/,%)
        echo Check dirs
        touch "$@"
```

Test output:

```
$ ./a.mak clean
echo [Clean]
[Clean]
rm -f *.png *.fig.py *.fig.raw.py

$ ./a.mak      
echo Check dirs
Check dirs
touch foo1_bar1.raw.fig.py
touch foo1_bar1.fig.py
touch foo1_bar1.png
echo Check dirs
Check dirs
touch foo2_bar2.raw.fig.py
touch foo2_bar2.fig.py
touch foo2_bar2.png

$ touch foo1

$ ./a.mak
make: Nothing to be done for `plots'.

$ touch foo1/bar1

$ ./a.mak
echo Check dirs
Check dirs
touch foo1_bar1.raw.fig.py
touch foo1_bar1.fig.py
touch foo1_bar1.png

$ vim foo1_bar1.fig.py

$ ./a.mak
touch "foo1_bar1.png"

$ ./a.mak
make: Nothing to be done for `plots'.
```

Comment: (referring to your first sentence:) I want to create `%.fig.py` if it doesn't exist. Let me read your answer first though, it's probably relevant :) ... (after reading:) yes I think that's the solution, thanks!

Comment: Hiya, thanks again for your answer. If I understand correctly, `touch @.fig.raw.py` is a placeholder for extracting the figure data (`GETDATA`)? This might not have been clear from the initial question, but this extraction doesn't follow logical rules. I thought it would be useful to have a different target for each of these `.raw.fig.py` files, to extract their data from different directories (see updated question). Is this still possible with your approach?

Comment: @noio: `touch` is really just the placeholder to help me to trace the execution path. It is not clear when `some_other_figure.raw.fig.py` and `yet_another_figure.raw.fig.py` should e generated. Or you are going to modify `plots:` target every time an other `png` needs to be generated? Also not clear why you have to edit the `raw` files after they are used to generate `fig` files. Maybe if You are writing the your work process I could make a better solution.

Comment: I was going to add all the different `.png`'s as dependencies of `plots:`. I don't need to edit the `raw.fig.py` files, I just have to fix the `fig.py` files at some point before generating my "final" figures.

Comment: @Noio: I added a second section to my answer. If the `png` file's name somehow can be generated from the name of the source directories then the **ADDED** part can be used. It also contains some improvements.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! There is actually no way the png's filename can be generated from the source directory, in reality, the `$(GETDATA)` command doesn't only take a directory as input, but a whole bunch of arbitrary parameters as well. Additionally; there are many directories for the same simulation, each prepended with their date, and the makefile contains the information on *which* simulation data—i.e. which date—to use for each experiment.

Comment: @Noio: it was just an idea. IMHO it worth to check it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is simply checking if `%.fig.py` exists:

```
%.fig.py: %.raw.fig.py
    test -s $@ || cp $< $@
```

And marking as `.PRECIOUS`, as @TrueY suggested. This requires me to delete the precious files if I want figures rebuilt, but I can live with that.

Comment: Oops! I misinterpreted your Q! I thought the raw file need to be edited manually! But it is the ’fig’ file instead! Sorry! BTW you can use the shorter and more common `[ -s $@ ] || cp ...` form.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your elaborate answer and solution, I learnt a bit about make again :)

Comment: I would not suggest to use the `test -s $@ || cp $< $@` command. It will always try to recreate the target. I may use `if [ -s "$@" ]; then touch "$@"; else cp "$<" "$@"; fi` instead. It will just `touch` the result file if it should not be updated. So next time if "%.fig.py" not changed make will report `make: Nothing to be done for `plots'.`. I added this version to my answer.